# mysql_query -- question about results "location"

Tags: php, mysql

Forgive me if this is a particularly stupid question!

```
mysql_query($query)
```

returns a boolean, but you can also assign it to a variable

```
$results = mysql_query($query)
```

and then use the other `mysql_` functions to extract data.

Out of curiosity, how does `mysq_query($query)` act as both a boolean and a data container at the same time? What's happening "under the hood" during these steps?

(yes, I am a n00b..., please be kind!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you notice, when it returns true/false, you can't use it with the other functions such as `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

From the [`mysql_query()`](http://us.php.net/mysql_query) documentation:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN
>   and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a
>   resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements,
>   INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success
>   or FALSE on error.or FALSE on error.

What happens, is for statements that do not return data, it responds true/false on whether or not the query was successful.

When there is a result set, you will see it returns a MySQL resource. This is a special value that allows PHP to figure out what data set you are talking about. You then pass this resource to other MySQL function to retrieve the data.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php

Comment: It's important to clarify that an object with at least one member variable or an array with at least one element is considered TRUE. Otherwise it's considered FALSE.

Comment: Yes, as Ben mentioned, at least in the case of `if` statements, something can be considered `true` but still not be a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that, Chacha. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
var_dump(mysql_query($query));
```

should tell you it's a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (as well as its id)